# Why does my child squirm so much while bottle feeding?

Tags: infant, breastfeeding

She used to be fairly intent and placated by feeding (she's 6 months now).  About two weeks ago she started squirming around quite a bit while drinking from her bottle. She arches her back and moves all over the place.  She's still happy and hungry, I just can't figure out why the change from calm to a total wiggle-worm would have taken place.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi my little princess does the same thing she is 6 weeks old and its like shes never seen a bottle b4. What i think it might be is the size of the teet. When we use the nxt size up she seems fine but vomits just a little bit more, and absolutly smashes the bottle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's what's great about parenting.  As soon as you start getting it down, it changes.  It's a stage every child goes through.  As they gain more control over their bodies, they assert it.  Try some different holds until you find one that works.  I've found two different ones useful.  One is to cradle the baby in my left arm, but hold the baby's right arm under my left armpit, so he's turned a little more toward me and is restrained from turning.  The other way is to sit the baby on your lap facing out.  It looks weird, but works really well for some kids.

Comment: I'll try the "arm hold".  Sitting up totally works sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

Probably because her vision is improved significantly in the last few months; she sees things much clearer now, and everything is FASCINATING to her - and thus VERY distracting.

Answer (score 3):

My daughter(6months old) does the same thing: she's very squirmy - will take a few sips, stop to look around, take a few more, stop and so on. I try to give her a blankie so she can feel the texture and although this sometimes helps, the only time she will peacefully drink her bottle is in the night time.

Comment: Welcome to the site Kristy!  Can you edit this so it follows standard writing conventions and uses fewer abbreviations please?  We want the content on the site to be easy to read for readers from all over the world, so answers that use "texting" techniques, abbreviations and non-standard grammar are discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

Mine does this too.  I hate to be the harbinger of bad news, but it only gets worse.  Your baby is only going to get more mobile, more energetic, smarter, able to see and process more, and therefore more interested in the world.  By the time my baby was 10 months old, she would take a few sips from her bottle, sit up, look around, lay down and take a few more sips, and lather, rinse, repeat.

What helped was giving my baby her lovie or another piece of cloth, blanket, or toy with interesting textures to hold while eating.  It doesn't work all the time, and it has worked less and less as she's gotten older, but at 6 months it helped a lot.  You'll have to determine if your baby prefers consistency or is better when looking at/touching a different toy/texture each feed.  It ran in stages for my baby.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post. But I am currently exercising the same issue with my 3 1/2 month old son. Upon researching the internet, I stumbled upon an article regarding SILENT REFLEX!!!  This was my answer !!!

Comment: Welcome! Do you mean silent _reflux_? If so, your answer would benefit from a few more details - what is it, how can it be recognized and what should the concerned parent do? As for all new users I recommend you take the [tour] and browse through our [help], especially [answer], to learn more about how the site works, then you may consider an [edit] to turn a keyword into a full standalone answer. I would like to upvote it.